# How to convert rgb list data to image in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have the following data :

`data = [0,0,0, 41, 250, 26, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 41, 250, 26,0,0,0,0,0,0,41, 250, 26,0,0,0];`

Each of the 3 groups is the rgb value， I already know the height and width of the image，  How to convert them into images？

Answer (score 0):

Check this package: [Image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image)

You can use it to manipulate images in your app.

Refer to the documentation:
https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image-class.html